# C# Large Object Heap is not cleared after Inserting large string in database using ExecuteNonQuery() method

Tags: c#, sql, memory-leaks

I am inserting **large string** data in DB using in `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

Above method puts the`byte[]` in **Large Object Heap** and it is not cleared even after calling `Dispose()` and `Close()`.

Rapidly calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` method increasing the Large Object Heap size.

Is there is any workaround that can resolve this issue?

```
SqlConnection connection = GetConnection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("<<Insert Query>>", connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demo", "<<Value>>");

int affectedRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Posting your code, for example

Comment: You don't control the GC. When it collects things - *especially* when it touches the LOH - is up to **it**, and depends on things like the memory pressure on the system, what GC mode (desktop/server) you're using, etc. It is **not expected** that things get collected immediately, and GC has *nothing* to do with Dispose/Close. If you show what your data access code is doing, there *may be options*, but: so far, you haven't actually described a *problem* - it is functioning exactly as expected.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Code added in question.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes exactly and even I dont want to call GC.Collect() [even though it wont called] . so is this a limitation of C#?

Comment: @MarcGravell Problem is that I am measuring the performance of my application using windows Performance monitor.
When it is doing some operations then there are some peaks in graph
but when it became idle then graph line should be go to the ground.

Comment: @VimeshShah no, it isn't; but it is hard to talk about specifics without specific examples; I see you've added an edit, but your edit **doesn't tell us anything** - what is the thing that is going into the LOH here? is it a huge string? is it a BLOB? you can only talk about these things accurately with *very specific examples*. In almost all cases there are ways of avoiding *perceived* memory issues (although again I emphasize: so far, you haven't actually described a problem)

Comment: "but when it became idle then graph line should be go to the ground" - why should it? it sounds like the GC disagrees with you, and I'm willing to bet the GC knows a lot more about making effective usage of memory on a machine than you do :) the objective of a good GC is not "use the absolute minimum memory at all times". But: we don't even know what GC we're talking about here - desktop GC and server GC behave quite differently. In many cases, it makes sense for a *server* application to use *desktop* GC mode, to get the different GC behavior.

Comment: @MarcGravell "what is the thing that is going into the LOH here? is it a huge string? is it a BLOB?" -> It is a large XML string.

Comment: @MarcGravell I got your point. Thank you :)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: There are cases when GC.Collect() must be called manually as otherwise an OutOfMemoryException is thrown. The problem is, that the GC is running on a thread with normal (or even less than normal? Not sure) priority, and in Windows threads of a lesser priority do not get any processor time until all threads with higher priority are resting. That means if you are producing nonstop garbage on a thread with a higher priority, you may be forced to manually call ```GC.Collect()``` (or add sleeps, but I find that uglyer and less reliable than calling ```GC.Collect()```).